# Can I get website analytics for past couple of days?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

Is there any way to obtain information for website analytics for the past two days if I don't have a plugin or anything like that already?

Comment: Your hosting provider probably provides access to the server logs for your domain, but this is not as detailed as Google Analytics or similar javascript based tracking.

Answer (score 0):

Google AdSense would help if you have inserted its script inside webpage. Another solution would be to look after traffic usage provided by hosting company.